# Robolectric 3.2: System.currentTimeMillis() not intercepted

Tags: android, robolectric

I have a minimal test case that doesn't work as I expect it to:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void testTime() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long start2 = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        long jump = 100000;
        ShadowSystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(ShadowSystemClock.currentTimeMillis() + jump);
        System.err.println("current: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        System.err.println("elapsed: " + (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start2));
    }
}
```

I'd expect the output to be the same for both current and elapsed but the actual output is:

```
current: 2
elapsed: 99900
```

I cannot get `System.currentTimeMillis()` to change, it's my understanding that in Robolectrict 3.2.2 `InstrumentingClassLoader` should replace `System.currentTimeMillis()` calls with `ShadowSystemClock.currentTimeMillis()` - is it not run for test cases?

Comment: Because that is what the documentation for ShadowSystemClock.currentTimeMillis() says should happen. Reference: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric-shadows%2Fshadows-core%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Frobolectric%2Fshadows%2FShadowSystemClock.java#L80

Comment: Just checked and you're right! Apologies for that.